# Unable to click span class element by Using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am unable to click on the link by using the following code:

```html
<div class="qrcode-footer-text" ng-click="toggleQRLoginFormView()" tabindex="0">
    <span ga-clickevent="" screen-name="auth-init/QRlogin" event-category="login_v2" user-actions="login_clicked" event-action="login_clicked" event-type="customEvent" event-label="">Login/Signup with mobile number and password</span>
</div>
```

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://paytm.com/loan-emi-payment'
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"_3SzD")]').click()
time.sleep(5)
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(@screen-name,"auth-init/QRlogin")]').click()
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? I was able to run the code with no issues.

Comment: i was not able to click the element

Answer (score 0):

You provided HTML code in that **ng-click** attribute is used.it applied to `<div>` node which is **not clickable**.and element is [Angular](https://angular.io) element.

I run this code in java ..

in this using [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.guru99.com/execute-javascript-selenium-webdriver.html) I can click on **'Login/Signup with mobile number and password'** button.

```
 WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".qrcode-footer-text"));

 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

**executeScript:-**

This method executes JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window in Selenium. The script used in this method runs in the body of an anonymous function (a function without a name). We can also pass complicated arguments to it.

The script can return values. Data types returned are

  Boolean

  Long

  String

  List

  WebElement.

**Note : You have to add the following imports :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
```